# MAC HPC GNU or MAC PORT GNU

Tags: gcc

I have been using the gcc compiler from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/index.php for 6 years. Unfortunately they are not using the most up to date compiler. I have already installed gcc 4.8.3 from mac port. Is mac ports compiler as reliable as the one from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/index.php?

In the past I have had reliability issues with certain mac port products especially their version of codeblocks. If mac port's gcc 4.8.3 also has reliability issues I think I would rather use the older version of gcc or download gcc from somewhere else.

Comment: You can't infer that if one macport is buggy others are - they are p[rots and the issues will be mainly due to the upstream maintainers (i.e. code block's developers) A good source will work in macports with probably just a change to the destination path

Comment: The latest gcc port in Macports is 4.9 why do you want the earlier one? Also what do use gcc for not clang - the parts of gcc you use might affect if there are any issues

Comment: @Mark Because I want to test code I write for public domain on as many compilers as possible. So when i write the directions I can say this code works in these compilers. But I will check out the 4.9 port as well.